# Magento 2 - Show validation message in custom container on product update page

Tags: magento2, product, template, catalog, validation

I try to show the validation message which shows if you enter a wrong value (for example 0) and try to add the product to the cart, in a custom place. I try to do this on the product update site, which shows if you edit a product.

Currently it shows just next to the input:

[image]

This works by adding the attribute `data-errors-message-box` to the input and adding a container:

#### THEME\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\item\configure\updatecart.phtml

```
    ...
        <div class="field qty">

            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span>

            <div class="control number-input">
                <button class="minus" type="button"></button>
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       min="0"
                       value=""
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                       class="input-text qty quantity"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box-simple-product"
                />
                <button class="plus" type="button"></button>
            </div>

            <div id="validation-message-box-simple-product"></div>
        </div>
    ...
```

This works great on the product page in **THEME\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml**, but it does fail on the **THEME\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\item\configure\updatecart.phtml**.

Why does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the script tag from this:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "validation": {},
            "addToCart": {
                "cartButtonId": "#product-updatecart-button",
                "cartForm": "#product_addtocart_form"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {},
            "addToCart": {
                "cartButtonId": "#product-updatecart-button",
                "cartForm": "#product_addtocart_form"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```